# Continuous or Scheduled Web Job not giving expected output in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-appservice

**Created a Console Application for printing the numbers in .NET 6.0**:

```cs
namespace PrintingNumbers
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Printing Number = " +i);

            }
        }
    }
```

Build and Ran Locally.

**In Azure App Service (F1 Free Plan), Uploaded this .exe file of above console application**.
Tried with Continuous, Scheduled at every 2 minutes.

[image]
[image]

**Cannot see any failures in the Application Insights Tab**.

App Service > Configuration > App Insights Configured:

[image]

***Could anyone assist me in see the cause of the failure of Web Jobs..!***

Comment: Have you configured your app with Application Insights?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/y37Mbeg.png - It is configured.

Comment: Ok..Will check and let you know.

Comment: You also need to integrate Telemetry configuration in the Code as well by Installing the Application Insights Nuget Packages.

Comment: Actually I'm not publishing the Console App to App service for monitoring to integrate Telemetry config. I'm just add the exe file to run the application via webjobs. I'm following this [YouTubeTutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxfliwpSQPM)

Answer (score 0):

Initially even my Web Job failed and unable to print the numbers.

[image]

The way you are uploading the Console app seems to be incorrect.

First, we need to zip all the files which are in the `bin\Debug\net6.0` folder.

[image]

- I have created another job by uploading the above shown zipfolder.
- Now Iam able to run the job and print numbers without any issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying we have to upload the zip file instead .exe file to the webjobs?

Comment: Yes,select all the files and zip it, then upload the zip file.

Comment: I will do. But a small doubt that how it worked for the user in the YouTube Video I have given - that user has uploaded .exe application and worked

Comment: Even Iam not sure about that. As I see he is working with older version `.Net 2.1`.May be it has worked for older versions,as we are using `.NET 6.0`.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Let me check the solution you have provided and will update in few minutes.

Comment: Hey @Harshitha, Thank you for your efforts and time, your solution helped me.