# JetBrains Rider IDE for Azure Webjob Development/Publishing

Tags: azure-webjobs, rider, jetbrains-rider

Does Rider support the development/publishing of WebJobs ??? I can't find any supporting material. Documentation pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We use Console Application to create [Azure Web Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started).

- I have created a Console app in JetBrains Rider.
- In the Publish Options, I don't see any option related to Azure.
  [image]
- Whereas for `ASP.NET Core` Web App you can see the option to Publish to Azure.

[image]

AFAIK, there is no direct option to deploy to Azure Web Jobs from JetBrains Rider.

- As an alternative you can configure Web Jobs code in a console App, Build, Zip the dll files and upload the folder to the Azure App Service from Portal.

[image]

Refer the blog by [Md Tahmidul Abedin](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-by-step-procedure-to-deploy-azure-web-job/) and
[SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76268887/19648279) for Uploading the build files from Local to Azure App Service Web Job.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, WebJonbs themselves are not supported. However, you may want to use the workaround above and vote for the issue below:
[RIDER-30591](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-30591)

Comment: I have voted for the feature. Unfortunately not many others have.